# How to show relation table column name in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have 2 tables "users" and "blogs".
The blogs table has a custom column named "created_by". I want to make a relation like while showing the list of blogs, I want to show the "name" column of the "users" table. I am getting error as "Trying to get property 'name' of non-object". Can anyone help?

### Model(blog.php)

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Blog extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function UserCreatedBy(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'created_by');
    }
}
```

### Controller(Blogcontroller.php)

```
public function index(){
       
        $blogs = Blog::with('UserCreatedBy')->get();
        return view('blog.bloglist', ['bloglist'=>$blogs]);
    }
```

### View(bloglist.blade.php)

```
@foreach($bloglist as $list)
{{$list->UserCreatedBy->name}}
@endforeach
```

[image]

Comment: Try to dd($list) in bloglist.blade.php and see if the userCreatedBy data is there.

Comment: One of your blog might not have a user, try to use `optional($list->UserCreatedBy)->name` in that case, and check in your database that every blog has a valid created_by that do exist in your users table

Comment: okay. I am trying

Comment: Thanks. Now it worked. Actually the column "created_by" in the other 4 rows of the blogs table was empty. that is why the error was coming. Thanks sir.

Comment: Ok the relation seems ok. Try this in your view:
{{$list->UserCreatedBy?->name}}
Maybe you have some blog with no creator

Comment: Thanks once again

Comment: But sir, the code {{$list->UserCreatedBy?->name}} is showing error if the "created_by" column is null for any row.

Comment: You can do an inline if: `{{ ($list->has('userCreatedBy) ? $list->userCreatedBy->name : 'Name not found' }}`